# PagingList View not displayed after deployment in azure app service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops, pagination, azure-appservice

I am trying to deploy MVC web app through Azure devops, there Paging List not displayed in my views after deployment into Azure App Service, but it is working fine in my local debugging.

**MyView.cshtml:**

```
<div class="footer-fixed">
    <vc:pager paging-list="@Model.PagingList" />
</div>
```

Instead of paging list items, it is passed as below:
**After Deployment in Browser Developer Tools**

```
<vc:pager paging-list="Paging.Razor.PagingList`1[ViewModelClassName]">
</vc:pager>
```

**PagingList.cs from separate project than MVC project**

```
public static PagingList<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int totalRecordCount, int pageSize, int pageIndex, string sortExpression, string defaultSortExpression, string action = "Index") where T : class
        {
            var pageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecordCount / (double)pageSize);

            return new PagingList<T>(items.ToList(), pageSize, pageIndex, pageCount, sortExpression, defaultSortExpression, totalRecordCount, action);
        }
```

Could someone please help me out with this ?

Thanks!

I tried to reproduced in my local, but couldn't. And tried to clean/redeploy but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the paging list, which is not being displayed after deploying your MVC web app to Azure App Service. The issue is that the paging list is being passed as **"Paging.Razor.PagingList`1[ViewModelClassName]**" instead of the **paging list items.[0]**

It happens when the issue is with the calculation of the `pageCount` variable, which is calculated as the ceiling value of the division of `totalRecordCount` by `pageSize`.

Check the parameters that are being passed to the `Create method are correct`.

```
           int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(GetProjects().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Index view

[image]

And also, the issue occurs with the PagingList object is not being properly serialized when passed to the view in the deployed application.

`Another way` is you can do it by explicitly converting the PagingList object to a JSON string in the controller action that returns the view, and then pass the JSON string to the view as a string parameter.

In the view, you can then parse the JSON string back into a PagingList object using a JSON deserializer like Newtonsoft.Json.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    
    var pagingListJson =   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.PagingList);
    ViewBag.PagingListJson = pagingListJson;
    
    return View();
}
```

**In Razor view**

```html
@{
    var pagingListJson = ViewBag.PagingListJson;
    var pagingList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PagingList<ViewModelClassName>>(pagingListJson);
}
<div class="footer-fixed">
    <vc:pager paging-list="@pagingList" />
</div>
```

For further information, refer to [paging-search-sorting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/perform-paging-searching-sorting-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/)
and
[paging.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/search/tutorial-csharp-paging.md)